# Are Cucumber and Gherkin alternatives to Mocha and Chai? Can Mocha and Chai be used with Java code?

Tags: cucumber, mocha.js, bdd, chai, gherkin

If someone can point out any other source on StackOverflow etc. where more info about this exists, even that will be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to write acceptance tests, unit tests or both?

Comment: These will just be System tests which would be eventually used in UAT and Regression . There are no Unit tests needed at my end.

Comment: Why they closed question? Seems very useful to know,,, I wish these 'organizers' really care about education.. Pathetic.. Just see how many views it has..

Comment: @Joe Not only the question was closed ,I am still getting downvotes on both the question and the answer I wrote after I got more details. I will probably delete the whole thing to stop getting downvote notifications.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cucumber is an acceptance testing framework which enables tests that are readable by non-programmers. Gherkin is just the syntax in which those tests are written. The implementation of those non-programmer friendly tests can be written in multiple languages including Java, Javascript and Ruby. For testing web applications, there are tight integrations of browser drivers (Selenium, PhantomJS, etc.) with Cucumber.

Mocha is a test framework in which tests are written in Javascript. Mocha tests are not especially friendly to non-programmers. Chai is just an assertion library used with Mocha. Mocha itself doesn't provide integration with browser drivers, but there are examples on the web of how to use Javascript browser drivers from within Mocha and at least one tight integration, [CodeceptJS](http://codecept.io/).

So, whether Cucumber and Mocha are alternatives depends on what language you want to write your tests in and whether you care about their readability by non-programmers. If you want to write your tests in a language other than Javascript, use a Cucumber implementation in that language. If you want tests readable by non-programmers, use Cucumber. If you want to write tests in Javascript and don't care about readability by non-programmers, both Cucumber.js and Mocha (plus a browser driver) are options. There are other Javascript-friendly options than Mocha, such as Protractor for Angular applications.

Regarding Java, any acceptance testing framework that drives a browser can test a web application written in Java. If you want to write the acceptance tests themselves in Java, you probably want Cucumber-JVM. JBehave is another, older, less widely used alternative.

Answer (score 2):

- Gherkin is just a format in which features are written with cucumber so leave it aside
- With cucumber ,you are able to separate feature files and implemented code which is not the case with mocha
- C.H.A.I. is an assertion framework which can be used with mocha to provide English like assertions
  For implementing B.D.D. mimicking cucumber , though Mocha itself provides B.D.D. style by their describe and it statements.
- **For styles like cucumber , I tried :**

  - mocha-cakes
  - mocha-gherkin
  - cucumber(dot)js
  - mocha-cucumber
  - kyuri

They all have their own styles.

Comment: Which did you end up using?

Comment: I ended up using mocha's describe , it statements . Overall all other styles mentioned above are still evolving and I was seeing issues frequently.